# Paypal Sandbox account with API Signature Asp.net C# failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, sandbox

I am using Paypal Sandbox account with Soap API Signature Asp.net C#

The same code works for me on live Paypal account, but it does not work in the sandbox.

Paypal sandbox throws error

> *The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel*

Is there any help please

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you try to connect to `api.sandbox.paypal.com` without supplying an API certificate. Try using `api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not say what Urls you are using, we can't say right or wrong.

Here are the Urls for PayPal.

[image]